# If(AND) formula, referring between tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a huge dataset which needs reformatting.

Currently it is like this;

[image]

But i need it to be like this;

[image]

I have got as far as this formula, which would be inserted into column 'Area A' of the second picture

=IF(AND(Table1[Cell ID]=Table2[Cell_ID],Table1[EUNIS_desc]=Table2[[#Headers],[Acid alpine, subalpine and extensive grassland]]),Table1[AREA],0)

However whilst this populates the first row correctly. All other blocks below in the same column just respond false giving "0" even when they should also have a true value.

Another problem is that the formula for some reason extends the table massively (down) with empty false values.

Kind Regards,

Harrison

Comment: Index/Match would probably work better.

Comment: Hi, ive lookedup Index Match functions and have come up with this formula. It looks like it could work, but at the moment is not. Currently the value returned is simply the first entry to the area collumn in table 1 for all rows below. Assume that "J2" represents the location of Cell id 1 in table 2.                                          =INDEX(Table1[AREA],AND(MATCH(J2,Table1[CELL ID],0),MATCH(COVER A,Table1[EUNIS_desc],0)))

Comment: try this array formula: `=INDEX(Table1[AREA],MATCH(1,IF((Table1[CELL ID]=j2,0)*(Table1[EUNIS_desc]="COVER A"),1,0),0))) `.  **Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter** instead of enter when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "Cell ID" is in column A in Table1 then on cell `B2` on Table2 you would place:

```
=SUMIFS(Table1!$C:$C,Table1!$A:$A,$A2,Table1!$B:$B,"Cover A")
```

You can extend this down to all "Cell ID"s and then copy to all types of covers just by changing the `criteria2` in the `SUMIFS` to each different cover type (ie "Cover B" or "Cover C").

Comment: Hi, i tried using this formula and it hasnt worked. It opens an open window popup saying 'Update value'. I navigated to the same document i was in, another popup came asking for the sheet in which to update the table values from. I selected the Sheet which contained the first table but still every block comes up with #VALUE!.                                                Ive noticed the formula as it extends down each cell ID calls A2 then A3 then A4 etc... This is a problem as in Table 1 each Cell id has multiple row entries. And whilst some have entries for all cover types, not all do.

Comment: The cover type is not listed for some cell ids if there is none within that particular cell. Having a true of false output e.g. false enter 0 would be the only way to do this i think?

Comment: @H.Tan the popup is probably cause you copied and pasted the formula exactly as I presented it. You should have replaced `Table1` and `Table2` with the reference to your specific worksheets. When it's extending down and calling A2 the A3, all it's doing is referencing from Table2 what Cell ID that row represents. It uses then that Cell ID for the conditional sum that matches the same Cell ID in Table1. Hope this clarifies it for you. Regards,

Comment: Ahh, i thought because my Table was called 'table 1' it would work. Cheers for the help. Got it working as this; * the #Headers bit is just a result of clicking the header name instead of typing each one =SUMIFS(Table1[AREA],Table1[CELL_ID],F3,Table1[Coverage Description],Table2[[#Headers],[Cover A]])

Comment: Glad you were able to make it work. It would have worked except that my table was `Table1` without a space and also might be case sensitive (not sure about this). Regards,